# Custom Keyboard Overlapping EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-manifest

Currently i am working on Custom Keyboard as per my client requirement. Every thing works fine for me except one issue. I Will explain clearly my issue in steps.

1. I am having a screen which consists of 2 EditText at Bottom.
2. When i am Clicking on Edittext, KeyBoard is working fine and i am
   able to enter the values also.
3. But My Problem is keyBoard is Overlapping Edittext which need to
   shown.

Screen Shot With Edittext:

[image: Screen Shot With Edittext]

Keyboard overlapped Edittext:

[image: Keyboard overlapped Edittext]

If have worked around in some scenario as in Manifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Xml Code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="0dp"
    android:keyHeight="50dp"
    android:keyTextSize="12sp"
    android:keyWidth="25%p"
    android:labelTextSize="12sp"
    android:verticalGap="0dp" >

    <Row>

        <Key
            android:codes="8"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="1" />

        <Key
            android:codes="9"
            android:keyLabel="2" />

        <Key
            android:codes="10"
            android:keyLabel="3" />

        <Key
            android:codes="69"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="-" />
    </Row>

    <Row>

        <Key
            android:codes="11"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="4" />

        <Key
            android:codes="12"
            android:keyLabel="5" />

        <Key
            android:codes="13"
            android:keyLabel="6" />

        <Key
            android:codes="56"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="." />
    </Row>

    <Row>

        <Key
            android:codes="14"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="7" />

        <Key
            android:codes="15"
            android:keyLabel="8" />

        <Key
            android:codes="16"
            android:keyLabel="9" />

        <Key
            android:codes="67"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" />
    </Row>

    <Row>

        <Key
            android:codes="7"
            android:keyLabel="0"
            android:keyWidth="50%p" />

        <Key
            android:codes="66"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="Done"
            android:keyWidth="50%p" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

And My Java code is

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        setAnimation(animation);
    }

public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private Activity mTargetActivity;
    /***
     * 
     * @param targetActivity
     *            Activity a cui deve essere girato l'evento
     *            "pressione di un tasto sulla tastiera"
     * @param mChangedListener 
     */
    public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
        mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

        mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }
```

When Declares in Activity

```
private Keyboard mKeyboard;
    public CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;

    private void setCustomKeyBoard(){

        mKeyboard = new Keyboard(mContext, R.layout.keyboard);

        mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);


        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(this));

    }
```

Hide and Show KeyBoard

```
/** Make the CustomKeyboard visible, and hide the system keyboard for view v. */
    public void showCustomKeyboard( View v ) {

        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(true);

        if( v!=null ){
            ((InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

        } 
    }

    /** Make the CustomKeyboard invisible. */
    public void hideCustomKeyboard() {
        mKeyboardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mKeyboardView.setEnabled(false);

    }
```

When I click on EditText following method will trigger

```
registerEditText(R.id.edtStop);

private void registerEditText(int resid) {

        // Find the EditText 'resid'
        EditText edittext= (EditText)mTradeCommonFieldsView.findViewById(resid);

        // Make the custom keyboard appear
        edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {


            @Override 
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                if(hasFocus){

                    mTradeActivity.showCustomKeyboard(v);

                }else{
                    mTradeActivity.hideCustomKeyboard();
                }
            }
        });
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTradeActivity.showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        });
        // Disable standard keyboard hard way
        edittext.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                EditText edittext = (EditText) v;
                int inType = edittext.getInputType();       // Backup the input type
                edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // Disable standard keyboard
                edittext.onTouchEvent(event);               // Call native handler
                edittext.setInputType(inType);              // Restore input type
                return true; // Consume touch event
            }
        });
        // Disable spell check (hex strings look like words to Android)
        edittext.setInputType( edittext.getInputType() | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS );
    }
```

Foll

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem with my custom IME and adding the following code to my InputMethodService subclass fixed it for me:

`@Override
    public void onComputeInsets(InputMethodService.Insets outInsets) {
        super.onComputeInsets(outInsets);
        if (!isFullscreenMode()) {
            outInsets.contentTopInsets = outInsets.visibleTopInsets;
        }
    }`